# How to speed up Quickbooks POS SDK queries with multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, quickbooks

I'm writing some simple programs in vb.net for Quickbooks POS (version 9) using the SDK v 3.0, specifically using the QBPOSXMLRPLib. Part of the program requires making a ItemInventoryQueryReq for the all of the inventory items. It takes about 3 minutes or so to receive the information for all 150,000 products. The program does not put a significant strain on the QBPOS server cpu, nor does it overwhelm our gigabit network, and so I thought perhaps we could make it go faster by making the program multi-threaded, perhaps splitting up the query by department and running multiple query requests at the same time. This was my first time using multiple threads, but I think I eventually figured it out - mostly.

To test things out, I made some programs that would get all of the info for two departments, each with about 16,000 products. All of the programs had two System.Threading.Thread 's - thread1 and thread2. Thread1 got the items from one department, and thread2 got the items from the other department. Each thread had its own QB RequestProcessor.

The first program ran thread1 and thread2 concurrently.

```
Thread1.Start()  
Thread2.Start()  
Thread1.Join()  
Thread2.Join()
```

The second program first ran thread1 and then ran thread2.

```
Thread1.Start()  
Thread1.Join()  
Thread2.Start()  
Thread2.Join()
```

Each program took about 45 seconds to run - resulting in roughly the same number of items per second as the original program(~150,000 in ~200+ seconds).

So I figured that threading had no effect. But on a whim, I made a third program that only ran thread 1 and a fourth program that only ran thread 2. When I ran the third and fourth programs concurrently, both programs finished in about 23 seconds, effectively doubling the number of items per second received. How can I get this same speed increase using threads?

Why are two separate programs running at the same time faster than one program with two threads? Am I doing the threading incorrectly? Or does this have something to do more specifically with the way that the QBPOS server handles queries from different programs versus different threads? If so, is there any way to trick the QBPOS server into going faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this has any direct correlation since you use `QBPOSXMLRPLib` and I use `QBWC` ... but within `QBWC`, I've noticed that requests are worked on sequentially within the same session ... perhaps there wasn't any fault in your code and it was slower because it was sharing the same session? Then it would make sense that doing the work separately in two different programs used two separate sessions and achieved the desired speedup...